# derivation of exponential distribution's expectation using poisson

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

I know that for a Pois$(\lambda)$ distribution, the expectation is $\lambda$. I also know its relation to the exponential distribution, and how you can derive the PMF of the exponential through the Poisson. With this, it's pretty easy to calculate the PMF and derive the expectation as $\frac{1}{\lambda}$

My question is, how you can formally prove the expectation of an exponential distribution, just using the fact it's a waiting time between Poisson points? I believe it must be possible because the expectation makes intuitive sense; if a poisson process has 3 calls/hr, then the average waiting time intuitively should be 1/3 hrs. I'm just not able to formalize this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi: The waiting time ends when an "poisson event" occurs, right. So, the P(X > t) = the probability that zero poisson events have occurred by time $t$. I think that should help you derive the distribution P(X < t). Then you can take the derivative to obtain the density.

Comment: Hey, yeah this is the method that I used to find the CDF and then PMF and then expectation. Is there another way though? Just with using the waiting time, maybe something like Y = number of calls in an hour, X = waiting time between calls --> E[XY] = 1? And then going from there

Comment: Hi APerson:  I don't know of another way. If you were able to get the correct pdf, I have a feeling that's the only way because once you start dealing with multiple poisson events, you're no longer in "exponential" land.

Comment: Hm I see. And the thing I said in the previous comment wouldn't work? Perhaps with Wald's Equality or something?

Comment: Hi APerson: I definitely don't consider myself an expert in the Poisson distribution so there may be a methodology that I'm not familar with. I would google for variants on "deriving the exponential distribution". I'm sorry that I can't be of more help. Were you able to derive it using the approach I described ?